# What is the shortcut to insert multiple line comment with * in the beginning in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know the shortcut Ctrl+shift+A in VS Code Linux to insert the multiple lines comment, but it just insert like this:

```
/*
my comment
my code i want to hide
etc
*/
```

How to get a comment like this?

```
/**
 * my comment
 * my code i want to hide
 * etc
*/
```

If I want to get comment like above, I need to insert manually like this

```
/**
*/
```

And every time I hit "Enter" inside that comment, VS Code automatically insert * like this

```
/**
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
*/
```

It looks like that kind of comment is supported in VS Code,

But I dont know the short cut to insert the new one without typing manually.

Anyone know the answer ? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE : VS CODE has update about this, more info : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_jsdoc-support

When you type `/**` VS code will know what you want and show like this [image]

hit `enter` and move your code inside that comment block

---

Look like there is no shortcut key for this till now, and if we want to that kind of comment style, we need to do it manually by typing this:

```
/**
*/
```

and hit "Enter" inside that comment